# How do I combine this 2 sets of coding together to form a mega drop down nav

Tags: css, navigation

At the beginning i was looking at how to create a mega drop down navigation therefore i went around the net researching and came about to realise that defining the width and position of each dropdown is the best. sorry if you couldn't understand but I found a js.fiddle with it too.

JS fiddle for the drop down navigation: http://jsfiddle.net/Pnn6V/9/.

However, i realise that the headings on the navigation (eg. Home, 5 columns , etc) are not evenly spread out as they are spread out be fixed px. therefore i went to research on how can i evenly spread out the headings. Then i found that actually by using CSS display: inline with text justify I can do the trick. Sorry if it confuses you. But i found a js fiddle for this too.

JS fiddle for evenly spread out navigation using css: http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/dqBNr/3/

I tired combining them together by adding the span tag and also the justify properties, I also changed the display to inline and inline-block but the whole thing messed up.

I was wondering if anyone have any idea what could i do to combine this 2 sets of codings together? Thanks a plenty. If you have any doubt of what i am talking about please kindly let me know so i can try to rephrase it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the headings are perfectly spread out, I assume you're talking about when you change them that the drop-downs get offset strangely. This issue is being cased because of these rules:

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column
{
    left:-841px;
    top:auto;
}
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns
{
    left:-2px;
    top:auto;
} 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns
{
    left:-736px;
    top:auto;
}
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns
{
    left:-248px;
    top:auto;
}  
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {  
    left:-110px;  
    top:auto;  
}
```

There are a couple of ways you could fix this. One by attaching to the onhover event using JavaScript/jQuery and setting the left to the correct position (#menu's left).

The other nicer way is to use the CSS position property to it's fullest. I got [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnn6V/38/) to work fine. I made the following changes:

- Added `position:relative;` to `#menu`
- Removed `position:relative;` from `#menu li`
- Added `position:absolute;` to `.dropdown_1column, .dropdown_2columns, .dropdown_3columns, .dropdown_4columns, .dropdown_5columns`
- Set the `left:0px;` on all the hover rules (eg. `#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column`) that used to have the specific pixel values.

This works because the `position:absolute;` on the dropdowns will now position to the menu's position, not relative to the menu item as before.

Comment: thanks for your explanation and solution...i work from it. Thank you so much

Comment: hi...hmm i was wondering the headers like the word 'Home', 'Design', 'Painting and mixed media', etc... could be evenly spread out using the inline property like in my 2nd [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/dqBNr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The element with the `width: 100%` has to be a sibling of the justified inline-blocks. In your case it has to be inside the `ul`. Take a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dqBNr/21/